# Que funcion cumple el 'instanceof'?

Tags: java

*Alguien me puede explicar que funcion tiene el instanceof  *
 `else if (getParent() instanceof frmEjemplo){ frmEjemplo.setText("texto") }`

Comment: ¿Qué has investigado acerca del uso de `instanceof`?

Comment: Hay miles de blogs que explican su funcionamiento. _Busca, investiga_. Si no comprendes algo en particular, explícalo en la pregunta. Lee [ask].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En resumen el operador InstanceOf sirve para saber si una variable es instancia de un tipo de dato.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

String nombre = "Programiz";

// verifica si nombre es una instancia de string
boolean respuesta1 = name instanceof String;
//imprime true
System.out.println(respuesta1);

Main obj = new Main();

// verifica si objes una instancia de Main
boolean respuesta2 = obj instanceof Main;
//imprime true
System.out.println(respuesta2);
}
```